# Make CSS more SCSS to avoid repetitions

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to make the following CSS styles more like SCSS and avoid having to repeat b:after for each heading tag?

```
h1 b:after {
    height: 0.7rem;
    bottom: 1.0rem;
}

h2 b:after {
    height: 0.6rem;
    bottom: 0.6rem;
}

h3 b:after,
h4 b:after {
    height: 0.3rem;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: There's not much repetition, the selectors and rules are different!

Comment: I agree with @sol, all the selectors look similar, but each rule is different.

Comment: Despite, if you want all the h1, h2, h3 and h4 b have the same height and bottom, give a common class name to h1, h2, h3, h4 and just type .CommonClass b:after {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you could shorten your code and provide some reusability is with a mixin:

```
@mixin someMixin($height, $bottom) {
  & b:after {
    height: $height;
    bottom: $bottom;
  }
}

h1     { @include someMixin(0.7rem, 1.0rem); }
h2     { @include someMixin(0.6rem, 0.6rem); }
h3, h4 { @include someMixin(0.3rem, 0); }
```

Comment: Great stuff!! Thank you!